# Send some or all params into a function based on a condtion

Tags: javascript

I am passing a set of params into the following function.

```
postData(
    param1,
    param2,
    param3,
    param4,
    param5,
    param6
);
```

But I only want to pass all params if a certain condition is met.
Else I only want to send the first 3 params.

I could do something like the following.

```
const condition = // true or false;

if (condition) {
    postData(
        param1,
        param2,
        param3,
        param4,
        param5,
        param6
    );
} else {
    postData(
        param1,
        param2,
        param3
    );
}
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this instead of this in Javascript?

Update:

```
const postData = (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6) => {
  return `${item1} ${item2} ${item3} ${item4} ${item5} ${item6}`;
}

const check = true;
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `${postData('param1', 'param2', 'param3', ...check ? ['param4, param5, param6'] : []  )}`;
```

When condition is true, ends up printing the following:

```
param1 param2 param3 param4, param5, param6 undefined undefined
```

Comment: put your `if` inside the function call and not outside... DRY

Comment: Is it likely that you would want to do something like `postData(param3, param1, param5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rest operator (`...`) and arrays to do it:

```js
const params = [param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6];
if (condition) {
    postData(...params);
} else {
    postData(...params.slice(0, 3)); // slice out the first 3 parameters
}
```

Note that this method is not *quite* equivalent since all of the parameters will be immediately evaluated to form the initial array, so expensive/stateful calculations may behave differently.  Something that would behave more similarly might look like this:

```js
postData(param1, param2, param3, ...condition ? [param4, param5, param6] : []);
```

Comment: Was actually liking your other option to spread only the additional params based on condition which is gone now from your answer. Though as you mentioned that may be expensive.

Comment: @stacky I realized that it actually doesn't evaluate the additional parameters unless the condition is true, so it's both shorter and faster. It's now back in the answer.

Comment: @vsync ...I didn't copy your answer though? I added this ternary operator approach in the 5-minute edit grace period, then promptly removed it in lieu of my previous approach because I thought it would evaluate the array anyway (of course you'll just have to take my word for it since there's no edit history). When OP then mentioned they liked the approach in the above comment, I thought about it again and realized that it does actually work, so I reedited it back into my answer.

Comment: The second option when true, ends up with 8 params where the last 2 are undefined.

Comment: @stacky Are you sure you parenthesized everything correctly? `console.log(1, 2, 3, ...false ? [4, 5, 6] : [])` correctly prints `1 2 3` and `console.log(1, 2, 3, ...true ? [4, 5, 6] : [])` correctly prints `1 2 3 4 5 6`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of working **DRY**:

If the order of your parameters is as you described then:

```js
const params = [param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6];
postData(...params.slice(0, condition ? 99 : 3)); // large-enough number
```

As you can see, this simply takes the array (of params) and using [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#quick_reference) together will slice will only take those which you need and use them as a chain of parameters.

Alternatively, another DRY method would be:

```js
console.log( ...[1,2,3].concat(true ? [4,5] : []) )
console.log( ...[1,2,3].concat(false ? [4,5] : []) )

// first method, where order of the array of params is fixed:
console.log( ...[1,2,3,4,5].slice(0, true ? 99 : 3) )
console.log( ...[1,2,3,4,5].slice(0, false ? 99 : 3) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional operators:

```js
condition ? functionIfConditionIsTrue(params) : functionIfConditionIsFalse(params);
```

And another example are the 3-dots in function parameters:

```js
let params = [param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6];
(condition ? postData(...params) : postData(...params.slice(0, 3));
```

More about conditional operators at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score -1):

> But is there a more elegant way to do this instead of this in Javascript?

An alternative method might be to use an object to store the param keys/values then pass in the condition and object to the function. You can then [get the values from the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) based on the condition. This way you don't have to worry about [the arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of the function arguments or the order they're in.

```
const obj = { param1: 1, param2: 2, param3: 3, param4: 4, param5: 5, param6: 6 };
const condition = true;

postData(condition, obj);

function postData(condition, obj) {
  const { param1, param2, param3 } = obj;
  if (condition) {
    // POST { params 1, 2, 3 }
  } else {
    // POST obj
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP wanted to call the "postData" function, you put the code inside the function

Comment: It's an _alternative_ method offering the benefits of using an object instead of a list of arguments. The OP did ask "is there a more elegant way to do this instead of this in Javascript?". I think this is more elegant.

Comment: And you shouldn't put "...etc" inside your code unless it is inside a comment, just in case people are going to copy/paste.